# jQuery - slideDown and push icons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a frontpage with a line of icons. The size of them are relative to the viewport. When i tap some of the icons i want to expand a div under the line of icons(iTunes-style) with some content. I use jQuery and have tried slideDown, with and without append the content to the icon-div, but it does not think of the rest of the line.

I can not separate each line with a div since number of icons on one  line is not consistent.

[image]

I have tried this library, but due terrible documentation i didnt manage to make it work, any suggestions:
http://thomaspark.me/project/expandingalbums/

**Some jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

   $('#1').on('click',function(){

      $('.dropdownwrap').slideToggle();

   });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="1" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> 
<a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div class="dropdownwrap"></div>
<div id="2" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="3" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="5" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="6" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="7" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="8" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> 
<a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="9" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="10" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="11" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="12" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="13" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.app {
    float: left;
    width: 14.28%;
    padding: 1%;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
.app a {
    display:block;
}
.app img {
    max-width: 121px;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdownwrap{
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color:#434343;
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jxkv5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Jxkv5/5/

```
<div id="1" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> 
<a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="2" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="3" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="5" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="6" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="7" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div class="boxWrapper">
     <div class="dropdownwrap" for="1"></div>
    <div class="dropdownwrap" for="2"></div>
    <div class="dropdownwrap" for="3"></div>
    <div class="dropdownwrap" for="5"></div>
    <div class="dropdownwrap" for="6"></div>
    <div class="dropdownwrap" for="7"></div>
</div>

<div id="8" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> 
<a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="9" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="10" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="11" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="12" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div id="13" class="app"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/121/121" alt=""/></a> <a href="#">Icon-Label</a> </div>
<div class="boxWrapper">
        <div class="dropdownwrap" for="8"></div>
    <div class="dropdownwrap" for="9"></div>
    <div class="dropdownwrap" for="10"></div>
    <div class="dropdownwrap" for="11"></div>
    <div class="dropdownwrap" for="12"></div>
    <div class="dropdownwrap" for="13"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $('.app').on('click',function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       var id = $this.attr('id');
       if($this.hasClass('active'))
           return;
       $('.app').removeClass('active')
       $('.dropdownwrap').css('display','none'); 
       $this.addClass('active');       
       $('[for="'+ id +'"]').slideToggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: Any easy way to slide away the "active" dropdown when i tap another? This seams like an easy solution

Answer (score 2):

I have thinked far and finally came to this solution .

**[CHECK DEMO ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/dUq3N/1/)**

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $('.app').on('click', function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();

                if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    $(".app.active").removeClass("active");
                    $(".dropdownwrap").remove();
                    return false;
                }
                $(".app.active").removeClass("active");

                var clickedElement = $(this);
                clickedElement.addClass("active");
                var dropDownAppended = false;


                $(this).nextAll(".app").each(function () {
                    var offset = $(this).offset().top;
                    if (offset > (clickedElement.offset().top + 10)) {
                        $(".dropdownwrap").remove();
                        $(this).before('<div class="dropdownwrap">Clicked On ID: ' + clickedElement.attr("id") + '</div>');
                        $(".dropdownwrap").slideDown();
                        dropDownAppended = true;
                        return false;
                    }

                });

                if (!dropDownAppended) {
                    var itemsAfter = $(this).nextAll(".app").length;
                    console.log(itemsAfter);
                    if (itemsAfter) {
                        $(".dropdownwrap").remove();
                        $(this).nextAll(".app").last().after('<div class="dropdownwrap">Clicked On ID: ' + clickedElement.attr("id") + '</div>');
                        $(".dropdownwrap").slideDown();
                        dropDownAppended = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".dropdownwrap").remove();
                        $(this).after('<div class="dropdownwrap">Clicked On ID: ' + clickedElement.attr("id") + '</div>');
                        $(".dropdownwrap").slideDown();
                        dropDownAppended = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                }




            });
```

this will works in any screen size, but you need to check, cause i have't tested much.
 and also you need to do something when somebody resizes the browser when dropdown is open.

hope it useful to you.

Comment: Any good alternative to animated remove()? like a slide up then remove? @Maulik-Anand

Comment: @simonkaspers1 : ya, can be done this way  , `$("class").slideUp(function(){$(this).remove()});`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to recognize how many icons in the row by getting the row width and the icon width. I have put a fiddle together for you. I think it does what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/qXR3X/

I made some CSS updates and a few markup changes as well, so make sure you have a good look.

The jQuery code is this:

```
//set the function as a variable of the window to be called later
window["iconSlider"] = {};

//setup basic parameters
iconSlider.config = {
    parentWidth: null,
    width: null,
    itemsPerRow: null,
    siblings: null,
    index: null,
    total: null,
    rows: null,
    position: null,
    container: $('<div class="dropdownwrap"></div>')
};

//init function to be called at $(document).ready();
iconSlider.init = function() {

   $('.app').on('click',function(){


    //get the row position
       var position = iconSlider.getRow($(this)),
           stopIndex = iconSlider.config.itemsPerRow * position,
           startIndex = stopIndex - iconSlider.config.itemsPerRow;

       var thisRow = iconSlider.config.siblings.slice(startIndex, stopIndex);
       iconSlider.openRow(thisRow);


   });

    //reset on resize
    $(window).resize(function() {
        iconSlider.reset();
    });
};

//getRow function - pass in the icon that was clicked
iconSlider.getRow = function (icon) {

    //set values to all our parameters
        iconSlider.config.parentWidth = icon.parents('.wrapper').width();
        iconSlider.config.width = icon.outerWidth();
        iconSlider.config.itemsPerRow = Math.floor(iconSlider.config.parentWidth / iconSlider.config.width);
        iconSlider.config.siblings = icon.parents('.wrapper').find('.app');
        iconSlider.config.index = icon.index() +1;
        iconSlider.config.total = iconSlider.config.siblings.length;
        iconSlider.config.rows = iconSlider.config.total / iconSlider.config.itemsPerRow;
        iconSlider.config.position = Math.ceil(iconSlider.config.index / iconSlider.config.total * iconSlider.config.rows);


    //return the row position
    return (iconSlider.config.position);
};

//open the row
iconSlider.openRow = function(row) {

    //reset
    iconSlider.reset();

    //when reset is complete, initiate the opening of the new row
    iconSlider.config.container.promise().done(function() {

        //make sure there is a row
        if (row.length > 1) {

            //for each item in the row, add a class 'expanded'
            for (i = 0; i < (row.length) ; ++i) {
                row.eq(i).addClass('expanded');
            }

            //append the container after the last item in the row
            row.eq(row.length -1).after(iconSlider.config.container)

            //slide the container open
            iconSlider.config.container.slideDown();
        }

    });

};


//general reset
iconSlider.reset = function(){
    $('.app.expanded').removeClass('expanded');
    iconSlider.config.container.slideUp(200);
    $(this).remove();
};
```

Call it in the document like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

   iconSlider.init();

});
```